# How can I move the player with roll animation in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 2D roll asset which is used to dodge and when I use that, the player's position doesn't change and after the animation, it returned its initial position. I tried to translate its position after the animation ends but it causes a jittering, how can I solve this?

```
public void StopRolling()
{
rb.MovePosition(new Vector2(rb.position.x + 0.54f, rb.position.y));
animator.SetBool("isRolling", false);
canMove = true;
}
```

This is the code I used to stop the rolling and update its position. I added the animation as a gif.

[image]